# Explain Similarity Transformation

Tags: matrices, group-theory, transformation

For two n-by-n matrices $X$ and $Y$, we know that they are similar if the following is true for some invertible n-by-n matrix $M$:

$X = M^{-1}YM$.

Can anyone explain what the $M$ and $M^{-1}$ are doing? In other words, I'm finding plenty of information that contains this equation, however nobody seems to explain why we need to use both M and it's inverse. I know for a vector transformation we simply front-multiply by $M^{-1}$, but for matrices we must multiply on both sides. Why? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of operation is present in many different places in mathematics, and not only in linear algebra, when you have "to cross the mirror" ($M$ operation) for doing things more easily there (Y operation), and going back in the "real world" ($M^{-1}$ operation).

I will take a geometrical example: If you are willing to express the angle $\theta$ rotation around a center $C$ which is not the origin, you will do a shift (M operation = translation $\vec{MO}$) then rotate around the origin with this angle $\theta$ (Y operation) which is simple, then go back to the initial point $C$ ($M^{-1}$ operation = inverse translation $\vec{OM}$) (remark : a translation is not a linear operation).

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) and so $X = M^{-1}YM$ is a similarity transformation (for matrices) but in all my courses we use $X = MYM^{-1}$ as the definition of the similarity transformation and the *inverse* similarity transformation as $X=M^{-1}YM$. Is this just a convention?

Comment: Yes, a kind of "convention", using the "mirror crossing" operation in the reverse way $X = M^{-1}YM=M^{-1}Y(M^{-1})^{-1}=NYN^{-1}$ (the other form) with $N=M^{-1}$.